# How can I generate a new G-Drive folder and duplicate template files upon a Google Form submission

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a Google Form which will capture details of upcoming projects. I am trying to write a script so that when a new Google Form is submitted (i.e. a new project is added) two things happen;

1) A new folder is created and named using the project code and project title from the Google Form spreadsheet
2) A number of generic template files (Google Docs) will be copied and placed inside this new folder and certain fields will be auto-filled from the spreadsheet.

I've done my best to cobble together code from a number of different places and I've come close a few times. I am fairly new to Google Apps Script and coding in general so I've hit a bit of a brick wall!

```
function createProjectFolder() {

// identify the sheet where the data resides
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);

//identify the cells that will be used to name things

var timestamp = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValue(); 
var projectCode = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValue(); 
var learningArea = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 3).getValue(); 
var projectTitle = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 4).getValue(); 
var extendedTitle = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 5).getValue(); 
var elevatorPitch = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 6).getValue(); 
var downloadableDescription  = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 7).getValue();
var tags = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 8).getValue(); 

//identify the parent folder the new folder will be in 
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

//create the new folder 
var newFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(projectCode + " - " + projectTitle);

}

function createGoogleDoc() {

// identify the sheet where the data resides 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);

//identify the cells that will be used to name things
var timestamp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValue();
var projectCode = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 2).getValue();
var learningArea = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 3).getValue();
var projectTitle = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 4).getValue();
var extendedTitle = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 5).getValue();
var elevatorPitch = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 6).getValue();
var downloadableDescription  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 7).getValue();
var tags = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 8).getValue();

//file is the template file, and you get it by ID
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); 

//We can make a copy of the template, name it, and optionally tell it what folder to live in
//file.makeCopy will return a Google Drive file object
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
var copy = file.makeCopy(projectCode + " - " + projectTitle, folder);

//Once we've got the new file created, we need to open it as a document by using its ID
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

//Since everything we need to change is in the body, we need to get that
var body = doc.getBody();

//Then we call all of our replaceText methods
body.replaceText('{{Project Code}}', projectCode); 
body.replaceText('{{Project Title}}', projectTitle); 
body.replaceText('{{Extended Title}}', extendedTitle);
body.replaceText('{{Learning Area}}', learningArea);
body.replaceText('{{Elevator Pitch}}', elevatorPitch);
body.replaceText('{{Tags}}', tags);

//Since everything else we need to change is in the header, we need to get that
var header = doc.getHeader();

//Then we call all of our replaceText methods
header.replaceText('{{Project Code}}', projectCode); 
header.replaceText('{{Project Title}}', projectTitle);
header.replaceText('{{Learning Area}}', learningArea);

//Lastly we save and close the document to persist our changes
doc.saveAndClose(); 
}
```

A new folder is generating but it is coming up with "  -  "  instead of the project code and project name. I suspect it is something to do with "getLastRow" but I'm not 100% sure. Also not sure if I need a new function for the 'createGoogleDoc' part of if it can be combined with the first. I'm also really unsure how to identify a folder that has just been created! Again, very new to this so apologies if it's a bit of a dog's breakfast.

Comment: I think that when you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue, it will be helpful users think of the issue and solution. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable **ss**, which you use to get ss.getLastRow() is a [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) while you need it to be the [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet). In your code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

**Spreadsheet** actually doesn't have [.getLastRow method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getLastRow()) which you want to use to get last row index. This is a bit confusing in documentation. This is why your

```
.getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValue()
```

is not working. You need to be calling last row from the **Sheet** of your **Spreadsheet**:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").getSheets()[0]
var lastRow = ss.getLastRow()
```

Also your code is calling same functions a bunch of times and this might cause some unpredictable results. Google script can have issues with cases like your.

Try updating things like:

```
//identify the cells that will be used to name things
var timestamp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValue();
var projectCode = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 2).getValue();
var learningArea = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 3).getValue();
var projectTitle = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 4).getValue();
var extendedTitle = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 5).getValue();
var elevatorPitch = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 6).getValue();
var downloadableDescription  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 7).getValue();
var tags = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(ss.getLastRow(), 8).getValue();
```

to

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]
var lastRow = ss.getLastRow()
var timestamp = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).getValue();
var projectCode = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue();
var learningArea = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3).getValue();
var projectTitle = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 4).getValue();
var extendedTitle = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 5).getValue();
var elevatorPitch = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 6).getValue();
var downloadableDescription  = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 7).getValue();
var tags = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 8).getValue();
```

But I would just get the entire row with one call.

Comment: Thanks @EvgenyVostok. Script is working beautifully now. The spreadsheet/sheet differentiation was the missing piece of understanding.